# Gap between statusbar to header

Tags: react-native

I have a weird gap between my statusbar to my searchbar inside my app.
This is how it looks like:
[image]
This is my code so far:

```
     renderHeader = () =>{
    return <SearchBar
    placeholder="Type here..."
    placeholderTextColor="#553A91"
    containerStyle={{backgroundColor: "#553A91", }}
    lightTheme
    round
    clearIcon={{color: "#553A91"}}
    textInputRef="search"
    icon={{color: "#553A91"}}
    autoCorrect={false}
    returnKeyType="go"
    selectionColor="#553A91"
    color="#553A91"
    />
  };


  render(){
    return(
      <View>
      <MyStatusBar backgroundColor="#553A91" barStyle="light-content" />
      <List containerStyle={{borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0, marginTop: 0}}>
      <FlatList
      data={this.state.data}
      renderItem={({item})=>(
        <ListItem
        roundAvatar
        title={`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
        subtitle={item.location.city}
        avatar={{uri: item.picture.thumbnail}}
        containerStyle={{borderBottomWidth: 0, borderTopWidth: 0}}
        />
      )}
      keyExtractor={item=>item.email}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
      ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
      />
      </List>
      </View>
    );
  };
```

inside renderHeader I create the searchbar from react-native-elemnts.

I tried to add padding / margin etc to try and fix this gap but with no luck.
What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

EDIT: I fixed the gap a bit by adding `borderTopWidth: 0` to the flatlist, but i still got a tiny gap. any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried using the inspector to see whats around it? It might be an added styling on the searchbar from react-native-elements

Comment: didn't know about that, I will check, thanks!

Comment: @ChiamakaNwolisa I looked in the inspector, had to add borderTopWidth: 0 to the list, but there is still a tiny gap, couldn't find anything else. any suggestions?

Comment: Hey @John Doah, I'm just seeing this, sorry man! Have you figured it out?

Comment: @ChiamakaNwolisa Sorry it took me so long to reply, yes, I had to move the flatlist up a little. Thanks!

Comment: Great!! @John Doah